# Deleting a specific folder and it's files ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, delete-file, directory

Alright so I'm having a bit of an issue here. I'm trying to delete a specific folder inside another folder on my webserver using ASP.NET (C#) The folder being deleted is based on a textbox.

The directory is like this

```
/images/folderx

folderx = txtDelFolder.Text;
```

The problem is that everything I try deletes every single thing inside the images folder. I'm guessing that it is not recognizing my folder in the filepath

> string path = @"\httpdocs\images\ +
>   txtDelFolder.Text;

I have also tried

> string path = @"\httpdocs\images\ +
>   txtDelFolder.Text + "\";

Tried all this with both single **'\'** and double **'\'**

Would appreciate any help on this

Also where it says `<directfilepath>` I actually have the filepath typed out, just didn't want to share that here.

****edit****

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/imagestest/" + txtEditTitle.Text);

  if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
  { 
  DeleteDirectory(path); 
  } 
 } 
} 
private void DeleteDirectory(string path) 
{ 
 foreach(string filename in Directory.GetFiles(path)) 
 { 
 File.Delete(filename); 
 } 
 foreach(string subfolders in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) 
 { 
 Directory.Delete(subfolders, true); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Use Server.MapPath() to get physical location of folders

Comment: @MikeTech Don't add code as a comment. It's completely unreadable. Format your original post and use the code formatting tools.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private void DeleteFiles(string folder)
        {
            string path=Server.MapPath("~/httpdocs/images/" + folder);
            string[] files=Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
             //then delete folder
              Directory.Delete(path);

        }
```

Comment: It's important to understand that whenever you delete a directory which is inside IIS Application IIS will unload your ApplicationDomain immediately (effectively re-staring your application). You might want to either use folders outside your application or remove only the files, leaving folders intact. Here is the link with a bit more details http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toddca/archive/2006/07/17/668412.aspx

Comment: Technically my directory is in the root of the site. Would this still have the same effect?

Comment: When I tried this it was still deleting files from /images/ and not from /images/folder/

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
public void DeleteFolder(string folderPath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            return;
        // get the directory with the specific name
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
                fi.Delete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I used this it didn't delete anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see why this wouldn't work:

```
public static bool DeleteDirectory(string input)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(input))
    {
        Directory.Delete(input, true);
        return !Directory.Exists(input);
    }
    else
        return true;
}

string thePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/images/");
thePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(thePath), txtInput.Text);

if(DeleteDirectory(thePath))
    Console.WriteLine("YAY");
else
    Console.WriteLine("BOO");
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try as soon as I get a chance.